# How the code is computed in PKCE with S256

Tags: oauth-2.0, pkce

In the PKCE flow, a pseudorandom code is generated and encoded:

```
B90Xq7Y6UhxU0SC9VyS1jZOC24S-H0fg6ScxriFboubD5mu-
```

And then for `S256` it is hashed and encoded via `base64url(sha256(code))`.
This gives the result of:

```
G0rGJ_-MUvTJ0-qvJxBqRULT2unY5V8_hqvnMpDRbEA
```

**How is this computed?**

I am missing a step since the `SHA256` of `B90Xq7Y6UhxU0SC9VyS1jZOC24S-H0fg6ScxriFboubD5mu-` is
`1b4ac627ff8c52f4c9d3eaaf27106a4542d3dae9d8e55f3f86abe73290d16c40`.
And it can be already seen that the base64 of this string will not match: `MWI0YWM2MjdmZjhjNTJmNGM5ZDNlYWFmMjcxMDZhNDU0MmQzZGFlOWQ4ZTU1ZjNmODZhYmU3MzI5MGQxNmM0MA`.

See also: [RFC 7636](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7636#page-17)

---

For the record, this can get the correct value:

```bash
$ echo -n B90Xq7Y6UhxU0SC9VyS1jZOC24S-H0fg6ScxriFboubD5mu- | sha256sum | xxd -r -p | base64 | tr '/+' '_-' | tr -d '='
G0rGJ_-MUvTJ0-qvJxBqRULT2unY5V8_hqvnMpDRbEA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're presenting `1b4ac627ff8c52f4c9d3eaaf27106a4542d3dae9d8e55f3f86abe73290d16c40` as the result of the SHA256 hash, but that is actually a hexadecimal encoding of the binary value of that hash. The binary value should be taken as input to the `base64url` encoding routine, not the hexadecimal encoding of it.

Comment: Are there any online urls that do this "input (code verifier)->sha256 (binary value)->to base64urlencode" conversion so i can follow along without writing any code?
I'm going from https://string-o-matic.com/sha256 to sha256 the input
then Base64 here:
https://www.base64encode.org
But not getting the code_challenge result.